# Oracle APEX 5 master/detail form -- detail region stopped working

Tags: master-detail, oracle-apex-5

I was adjusting some columns on a master/detail form and the detail interactive grid stopped retrieving rows.  I'm not sure at what point exactly that it stopped working, but I think it was when I was using the quick edit to adjust the height of the region.

I tried putting everything back the way it was, but no luck.  I added another interactive grid on the same table, linked by the same column to the master, and that works ok.  I tried exporting the source and comparing the non-working grid to the working grid, to see if something was messed up in the source, but I don't know enough to figure out what differences are significant.

Any ideas on what might have happened?  How I might be able to fix it, or at least avoid having this issue in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I switched the interactive grid to an interactive report and saved it, then switched it back to an interactive grid again, and that seems to have resolved the problem.